# vlookup and indirect dynamic worksheet name

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I have create a formula `=VLOOKUP($A2,INDIRECT("'"&"Z:\2566\4 COV\1 inout01\"&"["&"it_202301xx_io.xlsx"&"]"&"sbia_io"&"'!$B$10:$BK$277"),55,0)` and work but now a have many sheet (01-31) the day of month (xx) [image]

I want to copy this formula to another sheet and rename xx with date (Sheetname) anyone have idea for it.

Thank for help.

I don't have idea (macro or another method)

Comment: Don't use INDIRECT if you know exactly what Sheet you want to look into. Just change the day in the file name when you copy/paste the formula into your new sheet:
`=VLOOKUP($A2,'Z:\2566\4 COV\1 inout01\[it_20230101_io.xlsx]sbia_io'!$B$10:$BK$277,55,0)` Note that the tab names in your image do not resemble the formula.